# liveSplitters set to false but still show up in BorderContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout, border-container

I am a dojo newb so I am probably making a simple error somewhere.  I am trying to get a borderContainer set up without liveSplitters but even though I set it to false the splitters are still there.  The gutters:false property is reflected properly  Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

```
<body class="claro">
<div id="appLayout"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
    data-dojo-props="design: 'headline', gutters: false, liveSplitters: false ">
    <div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div>
            <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
            <p>para 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>h4 para 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>h4 para 3</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">Header content (top)</div>
    <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true">Sidebar
        content (left)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the splitter attribute from the content pane.

```
<div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
    data-dojo-props="region: 'left'>Sidebar
    content (left)</div>
```

The liveSplitters property describes the behavior of the splitters, NOT whether they exist.

```
// liveSplitters: [const] Boolean
//      Specifies whether splitters resize as you drag (true) 
//          or only upon mouseup (false)
liveSplitters: true,
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked like a charm.  I should have caught that...  So was the contentpane overriding the parent properties or adding one attached to the contentpane?